# How to limit number of category term display in home page grids?

Tags: plugin-development, taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

I want to limit the number of [categories](https://sprintally.com) to be displayed on girds to be 4 or something like clickable to expend all. but this should not be the effect on single post page.

[image: sprintally]

Thanks

Comment: Because there are many ways to create a grid. I think you might like to share more information such as how do you add the grids, by UI? By Code? If by UI, is it a plugin? a custom theme? If by code, what is the code? So that other helpers could provide help effectively.

Comment: @simongcc It is created by only a theme. I'm attaching the theme here " https://www.dropbox.com/s/mo1y2u2jw8mj6f5/boombox.zip?dl=0 ". please check.